# Как в массив меток google maps, для каждой метки добавить свой маркер

Tags: jquery, массивы, google-maps-api, google-maps-api-3

Есть код, но не могу понять как  добавить свой маркер для группы.
https://jsfiddle.net/Gorotto/rv4nz3tg/10

```js
 var gmarkers1 = [];
  var markers1 = [];

  // Our markers
  markers1 = [
      ['0', '<span class="city">Москва и Подмосковье</span>', 55.684578602223,  37.299261771164, 'classic'],
      ['1', 'Title', 55.763945799824, 37.616280192198, 'individual', 52.5, 4],
      ['2', 'Title', 52.4555687, 5.039231599999994, 'lowcoster', 52.6, 4],
      ['3', 'Title', 52.4555687, 5.029231599999994, 'one', 52.7, 4]
  ];
  // Info Window Content
var infoWindowContent = [
    ['<div class="info_content">' +
    '<h3>Mumbai</h3>' +
    '<p>Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>' +'</div>'],
    ['<div class="info_content">' +
    '<h3>Pune</h3>' +
    '<p>Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>' +'</div>'],
    ['<div class="info_content">' +
    '<h3>Bhopal</h3>' +
    '<p>Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>' +'</div>'],  
    ['<div class="info_content">' +
    '<h3>Agra</h3>' +
    '<p>Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>' +'</div>'],
];

var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker1, i;
  /**
   * Function to init map
   */

  function initialize() {
      var center = new google.maps.LatLng(55.731714493237, 37.56797370581);
      var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 10,
          center: center,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
         
      };

      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
      for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
          addMarker(markers1[i]);
      }
  }

  /**
   * Function to add marker to map
   */

  function addMarker(marker) {
      var category = marker[4];
      var title = marker[1];
      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(marker[2], marker[3]);
      var content = marker[1];
      var centroLat = marker[5];
      var centroLon = marker[6];

      marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
          title: title,
          position: pos,
          category: category,
          map: map,

      });

      gmarkers1.push(marker1);
 
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', (function(marker1, i) {
        return function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker1);
             map.panTo(this.getPosition());
              map.setZoom(15);
        }
    })(marker1, i));
      // Marker click listener
/*       google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', (function (marker1, content) {
          return function () {
              console.log('Gmarker 1 gets pushed');
              infowindow.setContent(content);
              infowindow.open(map, marker1);
              map.panTo(this.getPosition());
              map.setZoom(15);
          }
      })(marker1, content)); */
  }

  /**
   * Function to filter markers by category
   */

  filterMarkers = function (category) {
      for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
          marker = gmarkers1[i];
          // If is same category or category not picked
          if (marker.category == category || category.length === 0) {
              marker.setVisible(true);
              console.log(marker.centroLat, marker.centroLon);
          }
          // Categories don't match
          else {
              marker.setVisible(false);
          }
      }
  }

  // Init map
  initialize();
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 406px;
  margin-top: 10px; }

.map__buttons {
  width: 100%;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
          flex-flow: row wrap; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCzqbJ8_zNhqgtMWJL4M9bXDBcsyS5QXvo&sensor=false&v=3&language=ru"></script>
<div class="map__buttons">
  <button onclick="filterMarkers('classic')"> <span>Классика</span></button>
  <button onclick="filterMarkers('individual')"> <span>Премиум</span></button>
  <button onclick="filterMarkers('lowcoster')"> <span>Эконом</span></button>
  <button onclick="filterMarkers('one')"><span>Монокресельный формат</span></button>
</div>
          <div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Картинку я добавил, а описание у Вас выводится, просто кликнуть на маркер надо. С ховером, наверное, другое подход нужен. Но я не знаю какой

```js
var gmarkers1 = [];
var markers1 = [];
   var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: ''
});

// Our markers
markers1 = [
  ['0', '<span class="city">Москва и Подмосковье</span>', 55.684578602223, 37.299261771164, 'classic'],
  ['1', 'Title', 55.763945799824, 37.616280192198, 'individual', 52.5, 4],
  ['2', 'Title', 52.4555687, 5.039231599999994, 'lowcoster', 52.6, 4],
  ['3', 'Title', 52.4555687, 5.029231599999994, 'one', 52.7, 4]
];


/**
 * Function to init map
 */

function initialize() {
  var center = new google.maps.LatLng(55.731714493237, 37.56797370581);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: center,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
    addMarker(markers1[i]);
  }
}

/**
 * Function to add marker to map
 */

function addMarker(marker) {
  var category = marker[4];
  var title = marker[1];
  var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(marker[2], marker[3]);
  var content = marker[1];
  var centroLat = marker[5];
  var centroLon = marker[6];
  var image = null;
  if (category === 'classic'){
     image =  {
          url: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/grn-circle.png',
          size: new google.maps.Size(40, 52),
          scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(40),
        }
   }

  marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    title: title,
    position: pos,
    category: category,
    map: map,
    icon: image,

  });

  gmarkers1.push(marker1);

  // Marker click listener
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', (function(marker1, content) {
    return function() {
      console.log('Gmarker 1 gets pushed');
      infowindow.setContent(content);
      infowindow.open(map, marker1);
      map.panTo(this.getPosition());
      map.setZoom(15);
    }
  })(marker1, content));
}

/**
 * Function to filter markers by category
 */

filterMarkers = function(category) {
  for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
    marker = gmarkers1[i];
    // If is same category or category not picked
    if (marker.category == category || category.length === 0) {
      marker.setVisible(true);
      console.log(marker.centroLat, marker.centroLon);
    }
    // Categories don't match
    else {
      marker.setVisible(false);
    }
  }
}

// Init map
initialize();
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 406px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.map__buttons {
  width: 100%;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="map__buttons">
  <button onclick="filterMarkers('classic')"> <span>Классика</span></button>
  <button onclick="filterMarkers('individual')"> <span>Премиум</span></button>
  <button onclick="filterMarkers('lowcoster')"> <span>Эконом</span></button>
  <button onclick="filterMarkers('one')"><span>Монокресельный формат</span></button>
</div>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: чуть не то, мне нужно чтобы у каждой группы был свой маркер, или просто к каждой метки свой маркер.

Comment: если интересно обновил код, теперь при наведение один текст, при клике другой.

Comment: Я вас не понимаю. У Вас есть проблема с написанием условия?... дописал условие в коде

Comment: Да, для меня к сожалению это проблема. И у меня на данный момент 4 группы, и для каждой группы по маркеры.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  /* Map short */
  var gmarkers1 = [];
  var markers1 = [];
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: ''
  });

  // Our markers
  markers1 = [
      ['0', '<span class="city">Москва и Подмосковье</span>', 55.684578602223,  37.299261771164, 'classic', 52.7, 4, 'Plot 160, Mytri Nagar,<br> Madinaguda, Miyapur,<br> Hyderabad.<br><br>Phone:<br> 040 65081334, 040 65081335', 'img/CLASSIC_MARKER.png'],
      ['1', 'Title', 55.763945799824, 37.616280192198, 'individual', 52.5, 4,'Plot 160, Mytri Nagar,<br> Madinaguda, Miyapur,<br> Hyderabad.<br><br>Phone:<br> 040 65081334, 040 65081335', 'img/INDIVIDUAL_MARKER.png'],
      ['2', 'Title', 55.802853178794, 37.526128057152, 'lowcoster', 52.6, 4, 'ТЕКСТ', 'img/LOWCOSTER_MARKER.png'],
      ['3', 'Title', 55.727955197891,37.475995877251, 'one', 52.7, 4, '<span class="city">Москва и Подмосковье</span><span>м. Славянский бульвар </span>', 'img/ONE_MARKER.png']
  ];


  /**
   * Function to init map
   */
   if ($('#map-canvas').length > 0) {//проверяет наличие блока на странице
     function initialize() {
         var center = new google.maps.LatLng(55.731714493237, 37.56797370581);
         var mapOptions = {
             zoom: 11,
             center: center,
             mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
         };

         map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
         for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
             addMarker(markers1[i]);
         }
     }
       initialize();
   }



  /**
   * Function to add marker to map
   */

  function addMarker(marker) {
      var category = marker[4];
      var title = marker[1];
      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(marker[2], marker[3]);
      var content = marker[7];
      var centroLat = marker[5];
      var centroLon = marker[6];
      var image = {
        url: marker[8],
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(40, 40),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(31, 44)
      };

      marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
          title: title,
          position: pos,
          category: category,
          map: map,
          html: content,
          icon: image

      });

      gmarkers1.push(marker1);

      // Marker click listener
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', (function (marker1, content) {
          return function () {
              console.log('Gmarker 1 gets pushed');
              infowindow.setContent(content);
              infowindow.open(map, marker1);
              map.panTo(this.getPosition());
              map.setZoom(15);
          }
      })(marker1, content));
  }

  /**
   * Function to filter markers by category
   */

  filterMarkers = function (category) {
      for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
          marker = gmarkers1[i];
          // If is same category or category not picked
          if (marker.category == category || category.length === 0) {
              marker.setVisible(true);
              console.log(marker.centroLat, marker.centroLon);
          }
          // Categories don't match
          else {
              marker.setVisible(false);
          }
      }
  }
```